# Combining two stored procedures (select & update) into one

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm wondering if anyone can help me in combining these two stored procs into one.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMsgID] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SendingF      varchar(50),
    @SendingA      varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Prefix, Counter
    FROM
        dbo.Part p
    JOIN
        dbo.MsgIDG g
    ON
        p.ID = g.PartID
    WHERE
        p.Facility = @SendingF 
    AND
        p.Application = @SendingA

END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateMsgID] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SendingF      varchar(50),
    @SendingA      varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE  dbo.MsgIDG
    SET Counter = Counter + 1
    FROM
        dbo.Part p
    JOIN
        dbo.MsgIDG g
    ON
        p.ID = g.PartID
    WHERE
        p.Facility = @SendingF 
    AND
        p.Application = @SendingA

END
GO
```

First stored proc returns Prefix & Counter while the second increments Counter. What I want to be able to do is check if the first stored proc returns atleast one resultset and if so return the Prefix & Counter and do the second stored proc.

Is there anyway of combining these two into one that may be a bit more efficient than run two separate stored procs. I was initially thinking of using IF ... ELSE to check for resultset, return the two columns and update.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you can use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) like this:

```
UPDATE  dbo.MsgIDG
SET Counter = Counter + 1
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.Prefix,
    DELETED.Counter
FROM
    dbo.Part p
JOIN
    dbo.MsgIDG g
ON
    p.ID = g.PartID
WHERE
    p.Facility = @SendingF 
AND
    p.Application = @SendingA
;
```

The above will update the matching row *and* return `Prefix` and `Counter` as a row set, `Counter` containing the value *before* the update. Naturally, if a matching row is not found, nothing gets updated and an empty row set is returned, more or less same as with your current functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the code of you SP as following:

```
 SELECT Prefix, Counter
 FROM dbo.Part p
 JOIN dbo.MsgIDG g ON p.ID = g.PartID
 WHERE p.Facility = @SendingF AND p.Application = @SendingA;

 if @@rowcount > 0
    UPDATE  dbo.MsgIDG
    SET Counter = Counter + 1
    FROM dbo.Part p
    JOIN dbo.MsgIDG g ON p.ID = g.PartID
    WHERE p.Facility = @SendingF AND p.Application = @SendingA
```

Explanation: if the select statement returns the data, you will receive it as the result of the SP. In this case the update will also be executed. Otherwise the result set will be empty and no update will be performed.